# Remove blended text from raster image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, blending

I have this character I want to remove.

[image]

The interior of the character was generated using a known gradient map.

[image]

I can remove the character using content aware fill, but that does not take into account the information from the interior of the text. How can I reconstruct the background? Can the gradient map information be used to have something like an inverse gradient map?

My idea is to map the colors back to their original luminosity value, and do a content aware fill with a color blending mode, but I don't know how that can be done.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do an inverse gradient map. Using gradient map you will almost always have several luminosity values mapped to the same RGB color. No way to go backwards from that because the original information is lost. Besides that you also need to figure out how to remove the outer glow. Not an easy task all in all.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I don't really think this is possible TBH. If the gradient has been applied to the image directly, and you don't have a layered image file, it will have been a destructive destructive edit - replacing the colours that were previously there, essentially data loss - so basically there's no way to get it back.   This is why you should always save a layered PSD if you need to edit it in future, then you could just remove the text layer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you *can* get somewhat close.. and it will just take some careful color measuring and adjustments to get close to "perfect".

Your image, with a known gradient map in an area...

[image]

New gradient map (the same known gradient), but dithered and reversed.
Note the layer **Blend Mode** is set to `Exclusion` for this counter-map....

[image]

Then Hue/Saturation adjustment to bring it back in line...

[image]

It's *not* perfect.. but it's at least in the same general range overall. I did *not* spend any real time trying to get it exact, or closer to exact.

Answer (score 0):

The used gradient seems to be reversible - no color is used twice and the original has no color. Convert a stripe of your gradient to indexed mode with 256 colors and replace the colors in the color table (palette) with greyshades.

Then cut the colored letter area also to a separate image, turn it to indexed mode with 256 colors and change the color table to the one which has greyshades only. Paste the result back to the original.

Unfortunately a programmer is needed to sort and replace the color table. I'm afraid an ordinary user cannot know what's the geometric picking order used in the conversion to the indexed mode. I am an ordinary Photoshop user and cannot see anything useful in Photoshop's menus to do this.

The presented color table manipulation method is quite as useful as suggestion "eat more" given to a person who is starving. But ask a proper practical how to do it -method in some other site where GIMP scripting is on-topic and popular.